# Executing code to check database 3 times with few seconds delay

Tags: java, spring-boot, multithreading, timer

There is a need to develop a spring boot app that

1. consumes message from kafka topic
2. using id from message makes database call (check record in table), to determine further processing.

Due to legacy design/system, it is a possibility that there is a slight delay in process that writes records to the table. Hence, the message consumer (new) needs to basically check table few times before making final determination (the alternate solution to introduce fixed delay/wait in consumer itself is indefinite and potentially cause bottle necks for few million messages needs to be processed / day).

Researched few ways to achieve a few times table check (with few seconds gap), yet to find better way (if any)

- Executer Service
- Timer

Appreciate any advice/suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

### `ExecutorService`

The `Timer` & `TimerTask` classes were supplanted by the Executor framework added long ago to Java 5. So noted in the Javadoc.

### Problem statement

You want to repeatedly draw a message from Kafka, extract an identifier, and search a database for that ID to retrieve more information for further processing. You said the challenge is that the database may not yet have the necessary data, so we want to (a) wait with a delay to query the database, and (b) repeat three times before giving up.

You also mentioned a large number of such transactions, millions per day. Given your quantity, and given that your code involves blocking (sleeping for a delay, and waiting on a database call), your situation is a prime candidate for using the new [virtual threads](https://openjdk.org/jeps/444) feature arriving in Java 21.

### Virtual threads

In the nearly complete example app below, we establish an executor service based on virtual threads. We use try-with-resources syntax to automatically shutdown the executor service after a flag trips in our `AtomicBoolean`.

This code defines a task as `Runnable` where the task takes an identifier pulled from Kafka, and then tries to query the database three times. As we submit each task to an executor service, the main code immediately returns to fetching from Kafka. Meanwhile, a background virtual thread handles the task concurrently, performing the database query with delay three times. Because virtual threads are vastly cheaper/lighter than conventional platform threads, we can have millions running at a time.

The executor service assigns each submitted task to a background thread. As a `Runnable`, your task’s `run` method will be executed on that background thread.

If you want to track the success/failure of each task, capture the `Future` object returned by the `submit` method. In this simplistic example code, we ignore the returned `Future`.

If you want each task to produce a result, define your task as a `Callable` instead of `Runnable`.

### Example code

```java
package work.basil.example;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class TripleCheck
{
    private DataSource dataSource = … ;
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        TripleCheck app = new TripleCheck ( );
        app.demo ( );
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        AtomicBoolean continueCheckingKafka = new AtomicBoolean ( true );
        try (
                ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor ( ) ;
        )
        {
            while ( continueCheckingKafka.get ( ) )
            {
                UUID id = … ; // Fetch the next ID from Kafka topic.
                executorService.submit ( new PersonIdProcessor ( this.dataSource , id ) ) ;
            }
        }
    }
}

record Person( UUID id , String name ) { }

class PersonIdProcessor implements Runnable
{
    private final UUID id;
    private final DataSource dataSource;
    private static final String sql = "SELECT * FROM person_ WHERE id_ = ? ; ";

    public PersonIdProcessor ( final DataSource dataSource , final UUID id )
    {
        this.dataSource = Objects.requireNonNull( dataSource ) ;
        this.id = Objects.requireNonNull( id ) ;
    }

    @Override
    public void run ( )
    {
        Person person = null;  // Goal is to populate this object for further processing.
        // Try three times to find necessary data in database.
        int countAttempts = 3;
        for ( int nthAttempt = 1 ; nthAttempt <= countAttempts ; nthAttempt++ )
        {
            // Pause a moment as we wait for database to be populated with necessary data.
            try { Thread.sleep ( Duration.ofSeconds( 3 ) ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException ( e ); }
            try (
                    Connection conn = this.dataSource.getConnection ( ) ;
                    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement ( PersonIdProcessor.sql ) ;
            )
            {
                ps.setObject ( 1 , this.id );
                try (
                        ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery ( ) ;
                )
                {
                    while ( resultSet.next ( ) )
                    {
                        person = new Person (
                                resultSet.getObject ( "id_" , UUID.class ) ,
                                resultSet.getString ( "name_" )
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
            catch ( SQLException e ) { throw new RuntimeException ( e ); }
        }
        if ( Objects.isNull ( person ) )
        {
            System.out.println ( "Handling the null case, where no person found after multiple attempts for ID: " + id );
        } else
        {
            System.out.println ( "Handling the found case, where person retrieved from database for ID:" + id );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Basil for valuable suggestion and very detailed answer (and organizing problem statement). Definitely promising for apps on Java 21. But in our case, the app is on JDK 11 and it would be while before it could be upgraded to JDK21 due to company wide procedures followed (currently in process to upgrade to JDK 17 fairly soon). Could you please suggest similar solution with JDK 11?

Comment: Also please note that the identifier needed to query database is in the message JSON payload as element(sorry did not meant identifier in msg headers etc.)

Comment: @ArpitS For earlier Java, use `Executors` to instantiate an executor service backed by a small pool of those expensive platform threads. You’ll need to find a balance on a machine that carries enough CPU cores with enough threads to keep up with your volume of tasks but not too many threads where you overburden the OS and hardware. So just one line of code changes; the rest of the example code remains intact. (Java is amazing really)

Comment: still working on a solution where conditional retry are done (say few times) , and if any retry / attempt results in records being found, then no further retry are done. Exploring Spring Retry and Resilence4j

Comment: used resilence4j library to do conditional retry using predicate (only retry if needed). Sample code https://github.com/jobas2007/supplement-retry-sample